# How can I call `reciprocal` on the result of calling `sum`?

Tags: rust

This code gives the correct output of: `0.018181818`

```
fn main() {
    let v: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2)).sum();
    println!("{}", (v as f32).recip());
}
```

When I tried to join them in single line, I failed as the output type after `sum` is different than the required input type of `recip`:

```
fn main() {
    let v: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        .iter()
        .map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2))
        .sum()
        .recip();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:2:18
  |
2 |       let v: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  |  __________________^
3 | |         .iter()
4 | |         .map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2))
5 | |         .sum()
  | |______________^ cannot infer type for `S`
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

I've also [asked this question on the Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/working-with-sum-and-reciprocal/21026?u=hasanoryx).

Comment: `recip` is not defined on `i32`. Your first code sample has a cast to `f32` while the second doesn't have that cast. Also, it doesn't make sense for `v` to be an `i32` either in the second sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at the forum and like to share here:

```
fn main() {
    let v = ((1..=5).map(|x: i32| x.pow(2)).sum::<i32>() as f32).recip();
    println!("The answer is: {}", v);
}
```